# Java regex - match splitted words

Tags: java

I have a problem with matching words at the end of line, that contains dash (`-`).

For example:

```
circum-
stances
```

My `regex` matches this as 2 words `(circum, stances)`, But I need to remove dash and the sign of new line a make one word.

Comment: Could you paste your regex?

Comment: so pre-process your lines, remove any trailing hyphens and then run it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "circum-\nstances";
        System.out.println("[Original Content:"+str+"]");
        str = str.replaceAll("-(\\s+)", "");
        System.out.println("[Modified Content:"+str+"]");
    }
```

You'll get this as the output, I believe this is what you were looking for.

```
run:
[Original Content:circum-
stances]
[Modified Content:circumstances]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: This will also delete suspended hyphens. E.g. `nineteenth- and twentieth-century` would become `nineteenthand twentieth-century`

Comment: I think "-(\\n)" is better.